# How to translate context menu in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, contextmenu, zanata

I am working on a project that requires to be translated on multiple languages. I am using Zanata to translate everything and it works except context menu. I can not find anything in official documentation how to translate it. Regardless of language that I set on the phone it will always show english language in context menu(copy, select all, paste..)

[Example of untranslated context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8GGy.png)

I thought that it will be done automatically by operating system but it is not. Does anyone has the same problem and is there any solution for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Hey! This questions is tagged both `android` and `ios`, but the functionality referenced in the screenshot is iOS only. Is this a verified problem on Android as well?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, you need to add the supported localization languages in Xcode Project settings.

If the device language matches one of these languages, the system will show the tooltips in that language. The actual strings, as far as I'm aware, cannot be changed.

[image: Xcode screenshot (Project -> Info -> Localizations]

Additionally, you can define a [CFBundleDevelopmentRegion](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-130430) value in your Info.plist to define a default language.