# Is there any way to translate context menu according to phone language in react-native using expo?

Tags: ios, react-native, contextmenu, expo

So I use i18n library to localize my app's languages and theres no problem about it, except in context menu only in iOS. 
Even though I already change the language like Japanese it will always show English like (Select, Select All, etc.)

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/47558402/66972776-41d34100-f0c8-11e9-850c-a2aa6b913782.png

We have the same problem with: [How to translate context menu in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282253/how-to-translate-context-menu-in-react-native)

but I'm using react-native with expo.

Thanks.

Comment: Context menu of textbox like "Copy","Paste" or "Select All" is part of OS and not application level. Did you change language on IOS Level and not only the keyboard or app.

Comment: yes @Oleg,  I already change that one, including the region on IOS but still not working. It's a bit confusing why its context menu translations does not change when in fact is its part of the OS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to app.json:

1. add empty localizations files (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/app-stores/#localizing-system-dialogs-on-ios):

   "locales": {
               "zh": "./languages/zh.json",
               "ru": "./languages/ru.json"
            },

And

2.

```
 "ios": {
     "infoPlist": {
       "CFBundleLocalizations" : ["zh", "ru"],
       "CFBundleDevelopmentRegion" : "zh"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, great one you save me.
During my fix, changing infoPlist and not publishing the app and building it does not apply the changes. 
So after applying changes I publish and build the app  and run it to my device or simulator, Then voila. It works.

Again thanks.

Expo - sdkVersion: "33.0.0"